# Wordpress function and string as variable?

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, variables, query-string

I am creating something which passes featured image URLs to a separate JavaScript file which uses `parallax.js` to create a parallax background for each entry for an archive page.

This works fine when each post has an image.

I have been working on having a default image where there is no featured image but am having problems on pointing to it. I want to keep the path relative so when I upload to the host there is no need to have an absolute path.

At the moment it goes something like this:

```
if ( has_featured_image() ) {
  $image_link_url = $featured_background_image;
} else {
  $image_link_url = get_template_url() . 'images/placeholder_bg.png';
}
```

This does not work. How would I get the result I am after? Ideally want to have the function result and string at the end as one single string in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`get_template_url()`

user

`get_template_directory_uri()` for parent theme

and

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for child theme or parent theme if not child theme present

NOTE: this will require a slash like so:

```
 $image_link_url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder_bg.png';
```

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you, was pulling my hair over something this simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use `has_post_thumbnail()` instead of `has_featured_image()` and `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_url()`.

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    $image_link_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
}else {
$image_link_url = get_template_directory_uri() . 'images/placeholder_bg.png';
}
```

Comment: this is actually exactly how my code looks now. was on my mobile and im bad with wordpress functions from memory

Answer (score 0):

As far I've understood you want show a default image which you've store in a folder in your theme directory. So for that I think your code should be modeified a little bit-

```
if ( has_featured_image() ) {
    $image_link_url = $featured_background_image;
} else {
    $image_link_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder_bg.png';
}
```

Please try the above code. I hope that will work.